# Error while map reduce program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I am executing the Map reduce program in python on local system and getting the below error:

```
Password:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wordcount_mapper.py", line 7, in <module>
    filename = os.environ["mapreduce_map_input_file"]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'mapreduce_map_input_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variable `mapreduce_map_input_file` to see if it is set.

Type `echo $mapreduce_map_input_file` in your terminal. If it's not set the terminal won't print out anything.

Comment: yes it is blank, can you tell me how to set it as i am new to map reduce

Comment: That is the input file to your Map Reduce program. So you would just need to set it to the path to your input file.

Comment: Anyway, you should read the tutorial you're following again or find any related tutorials online about this. Surely they will have some example files for you to play with